# how to create accounts automatically with an email dictionary?

Tags: python

Hi im new in python and i want to create a script that creates automatically accounts in a page.

But i can realizy how to put a dictionary of emails in the code, for example i want that the code use a local dictionary(.txt), and automatically put one by one, the list of emails I have in my text file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/"

driver =webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Nahuel/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("lnkSignup").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("firstName").send_keys("manuel")
driver.find_element_by_id("lastName").send_keys("salis")
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys//Here i want to put a dicttionary of emails
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("pass")
```

thank you for your time and thank you if in addition to putting the solution you can explain it so I  can learn! Greats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposing you have a dictionary.txt file like this:

```
email1@gmail.com,psw1
email2@gmail.com,psw2
email3@gmail.com,psw3
```

you can read the values in the file with this:

```
emails_dict = {} #dictionary where the emails and passwords will be saved

with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): # if the line is not empty
            email, psw = line.strip().split(',') # strip to remove the newline
            emails_dict[email] = psw # add the values to your dictionary
```

then you can loop over the emails dict like:

```
for email, psw in emails_dict.items():
    #do something with that email and that psw
```

EDIT:

for your case the code should be something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/"

emails = [] # list where the emails will be saved

with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): # if the line is not empty
            emails.append(line.strip()) # strip to remove the newline

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Nahuel/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")

for email in emails:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("lnkSignup").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id("firstName").send_keys("manuel")
    driver.find_element_by_id("lastName").send_keys("salis")
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(email) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("pass")
    driver.find_element_by_id("signup").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but I couldn’t do what I was hoping for. In my dictionary I only have emails and as you see in the example I want to put each email in `driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("HERE)`  and then delete the email that I put. I got a little confused about psw, since in my dictionary I only have emails. Btw thanks for ur time

Comment: @lobffy just delete the password thing, i'll edit my comment in a min